# Location into an address

Tags: java, android, geocoding

I'm using the following code in order to convert a Location into an address(String).
It's working fine but sometimes the returned string is a city-level for example: "Israel, Tel Aviv".

That's pretty bad for me since I need to show my users where they are, and a city-level location is very undetailed. It's something with me code? or It's some exceptions that can't be handled.

```
public String reverseGeocode(Location loc) 
{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Update address field with the exception.
        return e.toString();
    }
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) 
    {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        // Format the first line of address (if available), city, and country name.
        String addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                address.getLocality(),
                address.getCountryName());
        // Update address field on UI.
       // Message.obtain(mHandler, UPDATE_ADDRESS, addressText).sendToTarget();
        return addressText;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: You could report a [developer bug/feature request](http://b.android.com) to Google. I don't think these parameters are in your control

Comment: @Reno Thanks for your comment but I really hope that you are wrong since it's going to be a problem for me. I will wait for more comments. Thanks.

Comment: Well I guess you are right, you can post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought, but you are only looking at the first entry returned via `address.get(0)`.  Have you checked to see if there are more results in your address list?  Given this comment in `getFromLocation` - "The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed to be meaningful or correct", I would say you can't 100% rely on the results.

Comment: Please try looping like iagreen said, also try hard cording lat, lon of popular streets to see what comes up. The GeoCoder works well in most urban areas

Comment: But the last parameter is the max returned values, and I set it to 1 so the second index will be null. I didn't wrote this code by my self I grabbed it from the android dev site tutorial. Reno it is an urban area.